# How to check whether a page is a direct or indirect child page of another page in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page with id 63. That page is having a number of child pages and each of the child pages is again having sub pages. In short page with id 63 is super parent to all the pages.

What I want is, I want to check whether the current page is a child of page with id 63. Either a direct child/child of child up to any level.

I am able to check the whether the page is a child of page 63. But not able to check the same for child of child pages.

I am using `$post->post_parent == 63` to check whether the page is a child of page 63.

How can I check the same for all levels of pages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $pageId= get_the_ID(); 
    function get_topmost_parent($post_id)
    {
        $parent_id = get_post($post_id)->post_parent;
        if($parent_id == 0)
        {
            return $post_id;
        }
        else
        {
            return get_topmost_parent($parent_id);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [get_post_ancestors()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors) like this:

```
$parents = get_post_ancestors($post);
 foreach($parents as $page_id){
    if($page_id == ID of specific parent page){

    // Do something

    break; //Match found, no need to keep checking
    }
 }
```